# PHP's mail() function doesn't work on GoDaddy dedicated server

Tags: php, email

I have a website that is hosted by GoDaddy on a virtual dedicated platform, and I haven't been able to get the `mail()` function to work properly in my PHP script.  I'm trying to send emails with validation codes to people when they first sign up to my website, and the `mail()` function works great for Gmail address, but not others like AOL or even GoDaddy's email service!

I tried talking with multiple GoDaddy support reps but they weren't really helpful on the issue. I've looked around online and it seems like this is a very common problem with people who are hosting their websites on GoDaddy.  I'm not getting bounce back emails when I the emails fail so it's hard to know what's going on.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$sendtoemail  = 'newsignup@aol.com';
$emailsubject = "Please validate your email";
$emailbody    = "Validation info, blah blah.";
$emailheader  = 'From: admin@example.com' . "\r\n" . 
                'X-Mailer: PHP' . "\r\n" . 
                'Reply-To: admin@example.com' . "\r\n" . 
                '-fadmin@example.com'; 
mail($sendtoemail, $emailsubject, $emailbody, $emailheader);
```

I've gotten a few errors when I checked `/usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog` (accessed through PuTTY SSH) that all ended in: `deferral: ./Maildir:_No_such_file_or_directory/`

I have also activated reverse DNS on my hosting account and created an SPF DNS record that sends email through "GoDaddy only" and checked the "Include PTR" box for DNS lookup. This was under the "TXT (text)" section of the "Zone File Editor" on GoDaddy's DNS manager.  (Hopefully that makes more sense to you than it does to me).

Comment: Maybe too many spammers from GoDaddy servers, so traffic is silently going into nirvana for some mailservices.

Comment: "I tried talking with multiple GoDaddy support reps but they weren't really helpful on the issue." Bad sign #1. Time to move to a better host.

Comment: Have you tried a basic `mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: {$from}");` call to make sure it's not your code?

Comment: What distribution are you currently using ? What MTA is installed on your server ?

Comment: The first problem was that you used GoDaddy for hosting.

Comment: There are better web hosting companies out there, Hostgator have been really helpful for me (apart from the "I have a problem, they check it out, all of a sudden my .htaccess file is missing and needs re-uploading") but might not be for everybody, their prices are good too.

Comment: @user1297088 I would make sure you are sending the mail through godaddy's mail server.  Godaddy tries to make you go through their gateway to cut down on the spam coming from their clients to prevent all email from godaddy's servers from getting blocked.

Comment: Apparently switching hosts would be the best course of action, but that's not really a possibility for me right now. @Pierre - I'm using Linux, if that's what you're asking. And the MTA is qmail.

Comment: @Andrew - I have tried adding the "From" field too but to no avail.

Comment: @Patrick - how do I get it to go though godaddy's mail server?

Comment: I used Pear::Mail, and you should be able to get the email gateway from your VPS information page when you login to godaddy.  Mine was something like s2smtp.secureserver.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if GoDaddy support PHP Mail, this is usually a big problem for web hosting companies because its used in scripts to send spam.

The best thing to do is check what PEAR extensions GoDaddy have on there hosting, if they have PEAR mail, you can use that. If not, then you should try using authenticated mail sending.

I can give you an example of PEAR and Authenticated mail if you need.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, I did some Googling `GoDaddy php mail() not working` and there was loads of stuff about it

Comment: I also looked around on google and found a ton of troubleshooting questions but no good answers.

Comment: @andrew - Yes please, I have no experience with PEAR yet, but I'm sure I could use it.

Comment: @andrewWillis - I installed PEAR and pear mail and it has the same issue... sends great to email providers like google, but not to many others.  Should I add SMTP?  What should I do differently?

Comment: include('Mail.php');
   
    $mail = Mail::factory("mail");

    $headers = array("From"=>"admin@example.com", "Subject"=>"Welcome");
    $body = "Message Here";
    $mail->send("monitor@example.com", $headers, $body);

Comment: @HarryBeasant  Please give me an example for Authenticated mail

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread, but thought I'd add my experiences in case they helped someone else.

I had very similar problems with mail(), and I called up GoDaddy's tech services. I was on the phone for 2 hours, and after 30 or so test calls to mail() (they even uploaded their own 'testmail' script), I hadn't received one email successfully (though mail() returned a value of 1, i.e. successful). The end result was that he told me that the email server relays were "queued up". After two hours, one tech support guy and his "sys admin"...still the same problem.

The solution was to use php library [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead of the plain old mail() function.  Emails sent immediately using swiftmailer. Hope this helps someone else!

Needless to say, I've changed hosting providers!

Comment: Why you changed hosting provider, and which is your current hosting provider?

Comment: I switched because I spent hours working with a tech support member, only to disregard his poor advice, over what I expect to be a trivial issue.  I've since moved over to dreamhost, where I haven't had any problems sending mail.

Comment: This is the answer! SwiftMailer definitely works with GoDaddy on the first try, using the ```smtpout.secureserver.net``` host instead of the relay one.

Comment: So glad you didn't have to go through everything that I did - I wish Godaddy would change their documentation. If it did indeed work for you, would you mind up-voting so others know?  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'm stuck on this problem too, but the documentation for swiftmailer says to install it. How do you install it on your godaddy server? I thought it was just supposed to be a library.

Comment: yeah this is old... but...
[1] using an smtp service will always work presuming your service is active and configured properly because obviously it's using that service and not GoDaddy
   [2] for years on dedicated server... i've been sending with mail() by virtue of GoDaddy allowing the dedrelay mailserver automatically configured with dedicated servers... but a telnet mail test (command line) to dedrelay returned with "Connection closed" [Nov 2 2023]

Answer (score 1):

your need to use default variables of PHP mail() for GoDadday, i don't know but when i used your snippet it won't work for me too, but by using standard variables, i got the mail; and yes don't use variable for dedicated email address, put in mail() function as i did, [image]

try hope will work for you too;

```
$subject = "Please validate your email";
$message   = "Validation info, blah blah. 2nd msg";
$Header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$Header .= 'From: Lux <info@luxstyles.com >' . "\r\n";

if(mail('info@luxstyles.com', $subject, $message, $Header))

echo "email sent";

else 

echo "email sending fail";
```

Comment: I tried using this exactly how you wrote it but it didn't work for me.  Are you using a dedicated hosting plan?

Comment: yes we are using dedicated sever, but this specific email id is shared taken from dedicated server! there shouldn't be any issue though :(

Answer (score 0):

So I did some work using php's mail function on godaddy deluxe hosting.  It would send to my gmail account but an actual email account using a domain that was on godaddy the mail never made it.   I have to believe that there are some sort of method to the madnesss.  My suggestion is try a different email if you aren't getting the mails from mail().  I know this puts a wrench in to your perfect setup of where you want the emails to go but at least you get the emails.  Perhaps you could use a forwarding trick to get the mail in to your inbox of choice once you actually get the mail.